# Using an INNER JOIN in a SELECT clause returning incorrect values

Tags: mysql, join, average

I'm having a problem reading the correct data from two tables, using an INNER JOIN function. What I'm trying to do is calculate the average value from column outbound-cost-pal from the table warehouse-cost-table for each country. This value should be inserted into the corresponding country in the table Warehouse.
I'll go straight to the code:

```
    UPDATE 
        Warehouse
    INNER JOIN
        `warehouse-cost-table`
    ON  
        Warehouse.`location-tariff-code` = LEFT(`warehouse-cost-table`.`country`,2)
    SET 
        Warehouse.`outbound-cost-pal` = 
        (
        SELECT cost.`average`
        FROM (SELECT * FROM Warehouse) AS wh
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  `warehouse-cost-table`.`country`,
          AVG(`warehouse-cost-table`.`outbound-cost-pal`) AS `average`
          FROM    `warehouse-cost-table` 
          GROUP BY `warehouse-cost-table`.`country`

                    ) cost

        ON wh.`location-tariff-code` = LEFT(cost.`country`,2)
        LIMIT 1
        )
    ;
```

The two tables I've been using are structured like this:

**Warehouse**

```
    |----------------------|-------------------|
    | location-tariff-code | outbound-cost-pal |
    |----------------------|-------------------|
    |          CN          |                   |
    |          JP          |                   |
    |----------------------|-------------------|
```

**warehouse-cost-table**

```
    |----------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
    |        country       |    Warehouse-id   | outbound-cost-pal |
    |----------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
    |      CN / China      |         97        |         1         |
    |      CN / China      |         98        |         2         |
    |      CN / China      |         99        |         3         |
    |      JP / Japan      |         197       |         10        |
    |      JP / Japan      |         198       |         11        |
    |      JP / Japan      |         199       |         12        |
    |----------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
```

The expected result would simply be:

**Warehouse**

```
    |----------------------|-------------------|
    | location-tariff-code | outbound-cost-pal |
    |----------------------|-------------------|
    |          CN          |          2        |
    |          JP          |          11       |
    |----------------------|-------------------|
```

My guess is that using the select statement inside the INNER JOIN function returns multiple values (Country and Average) which is causing the error. To avoid an error message, I have inserted LIMIT 1 to not receive an error message. I haven't been able to write this with only using one select statement (Average). 
Skipping the LIMIT 1 statement returns 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'.

Is my approach too complicated to begin with?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Including '-' in table/column identifiers is just asking for trouble. And see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to your code and your code sample you could use

```
 UPDATE Warehouse w
 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT  LEFT(`warehouse-cost-table`.`country`,2) my_country,
  AVG(`warehouse-cost-table`.`outbound-cost-pal`) AS `average`
  FROM    `warehouse-cost-table` 
  GROUP BY LEFT(`warehouse-cost-table`.`country`,2
) t on t.my_country  =  w.`location-tariff-code`
set  Warehouse.`outbound-cost-pal  = t.average
```